# Need ASP menu control that works on all browsers, including mobile

Tags: asp.net, browser, mobile, menu

I'm writing a web site (ASP.NET/C#) that is specifically targeted at mobile phones.

On the master page I have put an ASP menu.  This works fine in IE8 and Firefox, but when I try viewing it from my Nokia browser, while the menu is visible, its behavior is incorrect: I tap on the menu to open it, and instead of opening the next level of menus, the control disappears altogether!

Interestingly, I got the same behavior using Chrome on my computer.

I haven't yet tried on Safari, but the message is already pretty clear: the ASP.NET menu control doesn't work on the Nokia browser, and that is a showstopper.  What alternatives do I have?  It needs to work on Nokia, Safari and Opera, at least.

I saw in a similar question that [someone suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309674/need-a-good-asp-net-menu/309693#309693) writing a custom server control.  Nice idea, I'm sure... but how do you explain that to this ASP.NET newbie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that [most browsers support Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255048/which-mobile-browsers-support-javascript-and-ajax), so I'm going to use [Telerik](http://telerik.com)'s RadMenu.